# Trying to print out a map but unable to do so in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting data from firestore and wants to print out using map but it is giving an error

```
type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
```

My code is look like this:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: snapshot.data.documents[i].data['comments']
                        .map<Widget>((values) => Text(values['name']))
                        .toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

`SingleChildScrollView` according to its name expects single child. Its [`child`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView/child.html) property is defined to be of type `Widget`.

Method `.toList` also according to its name returns `List` which is apparently not a `Widget`.

What you can do here is to either use [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) instead of `SingleChildScrollView` or use `Column`, `ListBody` as well as any other **single** child wrapping your desired `List<Widgets>` into it. Refer to examples on [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) page for more information.

Comment: Now i am using column widget instead of SingleChildScrollView